# How to use grep to output home directory of found text

Tags: regex, grep

Using Ubuntu server ssh 14.04

My goal is to **find** all users starting with "any literal" in directory /etc/passwd and to output it with **their directory** in File System using grep

For example if i need users starting with "r" i will type command: grep ^r /etc/passwd

but i also need to output their home directories

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cut` command to pick out the 6th field from /etc/passwd, using colons as delimiters.

```
grep ^r /etc/passwd |cut -f6 -d:
```

or to get both name and home directory:

```
grep ^r /etc/passwd |cut -f1,6 -d:
```